# Apple watch Application not loading

Tags: apple-watch

I have created an application for apple watch. I have debugged it on the simulator, it works fine. But when I tried installing on the device it gets installed but it shows infinite loading indicator without any message or log. 
I have tried restarting both iPhone and Apple Watch, deleted and re-installed the application which seems to fail.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: It seems it is a bug. Somehow the same thing for my friends happens a lot.

Comment: Refer apple's troubleshooting guide. This may help. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode select iOS App as target only. Build and run it.
On the iPhone go to the Watch App, search your App and click "Show App on Apple Watch".

Sometimes this will help.